# How to change App.config to json config file in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-rc2

my project uses App.config to read config property. Example:

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxThreads"]`

Do you know of a library which I can use to read config from json. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

The `ConfigurationManager` static class is not generally available in ASP.NET Core. Instead you should use the new `ConfigurationBuilder` system and strongly typed configuration.

For example, by default, a configuration is built up in your `Startup` class using something similar to the following:

```cs
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

This will load configuration from the `appsettings.json` file and append the keys the configuration root. If you have an appsettings file like the following:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "System": "Information",
    "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ThreadSettings" : {
     "MaxThreads" : 4
  }
}
```

Then you can then create a strongly typed `ThreadSettings` class similar to the following:

```cs
public class ThreadSettings
{
    public int MaxThreads {get; set;}
}
```

Finally, you can bind this strongly typed settings class to your configuration by adding a `Configure` method to your `ConfigureServices` method.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ThreadSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ThreadSettings"));
}
```

You can then inject and access your settings class from anyother place by injecting it into the constructor. For example:

```cs
public class MyFatController
{
    private readonly int _maxThreads;
    public MyFatController(ThreadSettings settings)
    {
        maxThreads = settings.MaxThreads;
    }
}
```

Finally, if you really need access to the underlying configuration you can also inject that in `ConfigureServices` to make it available in your classes.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
}
```

You can read more about configuration on the [docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html) or on [various](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/may/23/strongly-typed-configuration-settings-in-aspnet-core) [blogs](http://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/)